# Transliterate by few different ways

Tags: javascript, algorithm, transliteration

I implement a transliterate function, and now result is `andrej` and `hannanov`, but I need to get also `andrei`, `andrey` and `khannanov`. Can I update my function without copy exist `map` and change few letters?

My function:

```
var map = {
    'а': 'a', 'б': 'b', 'в': 'v', 'г': 'g', 'д': 'd', 'е': 'e', 'ё': 'yo', 'ж': 'zh',
    'з': 'z', 'и': 'i', 'й': 'j', 'к': 'k', 'л': 'l', 'м': 'm', 'н': 'n', 'о': 'o',
    'п': 'p', 'р': 'r', 'с': 's', 'т': 't', 'у': 'u', 'ф': 'f', 'х': 'h', 'ц': 'c',
    'ч': 'ch', 'ш': 'sh', 'щ': 'sh', 'ъ': '', 'ы': 'y', 'ь': '', 'э': 'e', 'ю': 'yu',
    'я': 'ya', ' ': ' '
};

function fn (string) {
    var result = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < string.length; ++i) {
      result += map[string[i]];
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(fn('андрей'));
console.log(fn('ханнанов'));
```

Comment: Hello. I'm not sure if I understood what you mean. Do you need `fn('андрей')` to output `andrej`, `andrei` and `andrey`? How do you want it, inside an array, concatenated or inside another object?

Comment: Hi! Will be good in array, however I will be happy have any option

Comment: I need you to write down every rule that your algorithm must follow. For example, it seems to me that you want `й` to show `i`, `j` and `y`. Please specify every transliteration rule.

Comment: OP, please check the code and tell me if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var map = {
    'а': ['a'],
    'б': ['b'],
    'в': ['v'],
    'г': ['g'],
    'д': ['d'],
    'е': ['e'],
    'ё': ['yo'],
    'ж': ['zh'],
    'з': ['z'],
    'и': ['i'],
    'й': ['i', 'j', 'y'],
    'к': ['k'],
    'л': ['l'],
    'м': ['m'],
    'н': ['n'],
    'о': ['o'],
    'п': ['p'],
    'р': ['r'],
    'с': ['s'],
    'т': ['t'],
    'у': ['u'],
    'ф': ['f'],
    'х': ['h', 'kh'],
    'ц': ['c'],
    'ч': ['ch'],
    'ш': ['sh'],
    'щ': ['sh'],
    'ъ': [''],
    'ы': ['y'],
    'ь': [''],
    'э': ['e'],
    'ю': ['yu'],
    'я': ['ya']
};

function transliterate (source) {
    var result = [''];

    for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        if (map[source[i]] !== undefined) {
            result = addMappedLetter(result, map[source[i]]);
        } else {
            result = addMappedLetter(result, [source[i]]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

function addMappedLetter (source, letter) {
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < letter.length; j++) {
            result[(i * letter.length) + j] = source[i] + letter[j];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I know you wanted to make minimum modification to your `map`, but it won't work unless you assign arrays to its properties. My code will simply copy anything that's not mapped, so you can use it even if there are unmapped characters.
As far as I can tell, it works. I've tried this:

```
transliterate('2хйпу@hotmail.com').forEach(function(entry){console.log(entry)});
// console: undefined
//          "2hipu@hotmail.com"
//          "2hjpu@hotmail.com"
//          "2hypu@hotmail.com"
//          "2khipu@hotmail.com"
//          "2khjpu@hotmail.com"
//          "2khypu@hotmail.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

What about representing the different possible transliterations using arrays and using recursion to enumerate all the possibilities:

```
var map = {
  'а': 'a', 'б': 'b', 'в': 'v', 'г': 'g', 'д': 'd', 'е': 'e', 'ё': 'yo', 'ж': 'zh',
  'з': 'z', 'и': 'i', 'й': ['j', 'i'], 'к': 'k', 'л': 'l', 'м': 'm', 'н': 'n', 'о': 'o',
  'п': 'p', 'р': 'r', 'с': 's', 'т': 't', 'у': 'u', 'ф': 'f', 'х': ['h', 'kh'], 'ц': 'c',
  'ч': 'ch', 'ш': 'sh', 'щ': 'sh', 'ъ': '', 'ы': 'y', 'ь': '', 'э': 'e', 'ю': 'yu',
  'я': 'ya', ' ': ' '
};

function fn(string, partial) {

  partial = !!partial ? partial : '';

  var branched = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; ++i) {

    if (typeof map[string[i]] === 'object') {

      for (var j = 0 ; j < map[string[i]].length ; ++j) {
        branched = true;
        fn(string.substring(i + 1), partial + map[string[i]][j]);
      }


    } else {
      partial += map[string[i]];
    }
  }

  if (!branched) {
    results.push(partial);
  }
}

var results = [];

fn('андрей');
console.log(results);

results = [];
fn('ханнанов');
console.log(results);
```